# When to use mutable objects?

Tags: oop

There are tons of articles and blog posts over the internet telling that mutable objects are bad and that we shouldn't use them and therefore we shall make all our objects immutable.

I have nothing against this except that the topic has gone so far that some people might be "tricked" into thinking that mutable objects shall never be used at all.

When do we have to resort to use mutable objects? What are the common kinds of problems that are unsolvable without using mutable state?

Comment: but also, it is considered too broad to ask 2 distinct questions in one post. You might want to separate into 2 questions, and then maybe post a link from one to the other.

Comment: I think tag java is inappropriate as question is related to software design and not to  a specific language.

Comment: I've followed your suggestions, trimmed the second question and removed the java tag

Comment: @MarcoRomano excellent. I'm not sure why you got downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

As to your fear, it's common. Every concept gets taken by some as to mean that nothing else shall ever be done, for any reason.
These are the people who try to make requirements fit their ideology, rather than the other way around (a.k.a. they're not pragmatic).

When to use mutables? Basically when you feel like it, when you think it makes sense.
Prime example is in low memory and high performance situations where creating a new instance that's identical except for one little thing from the old one is too expensive in either memory and/or CPU cycles.

Comment: "These are the people who try to make requirements fit their ideology" this concept sounds interesting to me, can you elaborate a bit on it or point me to some relevant articles/papers about it?